# Corrupted MySQL functions? Syntax error returned against COUNT function

Tags: mysql, corruption

Very simply, we have made no changes to server or web apps but today we are receiving an error on any query which includes the COUNT function.

My suspicion is that somehow MYSQL has corrupted making the COUNT (and possibly other) functions unusable. At the most basic, "select count(1)" works on a working db server but against all databases on the server in question it returns the below error.

```
[SQL] select count(1)
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(1)' at line 1
```

I have not been able to find info relating to this as querying for "corruption" returns info relating to data corruption.

So my questions:

1. Is it possible for MySQL functions to become corrupted?
2. What course of action would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select count(1)` does not make any sense, and will not generate that error. Are you 100% you are showing us the **complete** SQL you are running?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `select count(1)` without a table name does work on mysql - it just returns 1 - and can be useful as a connection check for connection pools.

Comment: Can't predict on corruption, unless you show us the steps used in creating the sql statement and the statement too.

Comment: @lreeder: I didn't say it doesn't work, just that it doesn't make sense (although I would use `select 1` as a validation query, rather than adding a function to the call). And "*on any query which includes the COUNT function*" pretty much implies that `select count(1)` is **not** the real statement.

Comment: Consider posting your question on dba.stackexchange.com.  You'll  get a more focused DB-specific audience there.

Comment: My best guess is that there is some system configuration parameter that would have this effect.  I don't know what it is, and I second the recommendation to post this question to dba.stackexchange.com.